# Handle an exception in another method without losing the request objects from original one

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

There is an Exception that is thrown *when an user is not found in database* and i'd like to handle that particular exception *from the controller perspective layer in a separated method by @ExceptionHandler annotation* **without losing the original data sent by the user**. Well, so, *i'm using Sessions* and my first attempt was trying to get the object back from it by HttpServletRequest but i got:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'pontoEditar' available as request attribute
```

The code:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConversionFailException.class)
public String handleConversionFailException(HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes attr) {

    PontoEditarDTO ponto = (PontoEditarDTO) request.getAttribute("pontoEditar");
    // I'd like to get the original object back ...     

    return "pontos/editar";
}
```

### How would it be if i use a try-catch block

```
@PostMapping
public String editar(@ModelAttribute("pontoEditar") PontoEditarDTO ponto, HttpSession session) {
    
    // ... simplified.
    Ponto pontoConvertido = null;
    try {
        pontoConvertido = pontoConverter.convert(ponto);
    catch (ConversionFailException ex) {
        attr.addFlashAttribute("error", "User not found!");
        return "redirect:/ponto/listar";
    }

    // ... 
    return "redirect:/ponto/listar";
}
```

Here the simplified code:

```
public class ConversionFailException extends RuntimeException {
    public ConversionFailException(String mensagem) {
        super(mensagem);
    }
}
```

- Controller with POST.

**The exception happens in the POST at line with: Ponto pontoConvertido = pontoConverter.convert(ponto);**

```
    @Controller
    @SessionAttributes("pontoEditar")
    @RequestMapping("/ponto/editar")
    public class PontoEditarController {
        
        // ... GET Removed.

        @PostMapping
        public String editar(@ModelAttribute("pontoEditar") PontoEditarDTO ponto, HttpSession session) {
            
            // ... simplified.
            Ponto pontoConvertido = pontoConverter.convert(ponto);
            // ... 
            return "redirect:/ponto/listar";
        }
        
        @ExceptionHandler(ConversionFailException.class)
        public String handleConversionFailException(HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes attr) {
            attr.addFlashAttribute("falha", "Usuário não foi encontrado");
            
            /* I tried but it failed, how can i get ? */
            PontoEditarDTO ponto = (PontoEditarDTO) request.getAttribute("pontoEditar");
            

            return "pontos/editar";
        }
        
        @GetMapping("pontoEditar")
        public PontoEditarDTO getPontoModel() {
            return new PontoEditarDTO();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `WebRequest` (or HttpSession, etc...) as a parameter in your exception handler, it will be injected by Spring.

You can have a look at the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) to see what parameter can be injected by Spring when the handler is called.

Comment: It worked with HttpSession, thanks.